# Generate random string bigger than other string

Tags: python

I dont want to go into too much detail to keep interest, so here is the gist of it.

I'm retrieving 8-char strings from a database (EX: T12C4F6Z). I need to keep generating 8-chars strings but they need to be unique. Instead of checking if the string exists against everything from the database (or query the DB every time), i want to constrain the generation to anything bigger than the MAX the database has. This will avoid collisions and also i'm not going to need to check if it already exists every time.

Im doing the string generation like this:

```
alphabet = "0123456789ASD....."
return ''.join(random.choices(alphabet, k=8))
```

Without having to loop to check until the new string is bigger than the max, does anyone have an idea on how to constrain the generation?

**EDIT**:

I'm trying to make the process faster.
If the max string is = ZZZZZZZZX, i don't want to start generating strings that already exist, the idea is for the generation to be constrained to ZZZZZZZY and ZZZZZZZZ (because everything else would be a collision)

Comment: What do you mean by "bigger"? Lexicographic order?

Comment: `min( incr(MAX) , ''.join(random.choices(alphabet, k=8)) )` where incr = lambda m: str(int(m, len(alphabet) + random.randint(5). Not sure, would it be random enough for you

Comment: It sure seems like you will quickly exhaust your search space with this method. On each guess you have a 50% chance of reducing your available choices by half. Consider the very real possibility that one of your random guess is `Zxxxxxxx` and then shortly after `ZZxxxxxx`.  Now your space is only 6 characters instead of 8. Having larger strings and using UUIDs is a frequent way of dealing with this.

Comment: Mark, you are right. I need to change the approach. I was assuming that the already created strings do not have gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your recent replies, might I suggest you not worry too much about the collisions and take an approach such as this:

```
import random
import string
string_set = set()
# Just digits at chars is 36 possibilities
chars = string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase

# For an 8 character string note that there are 36^8 possibilities
N = 8
gen_str = lambda: ''.join(random.choices(chars, k=N))
# This is about 3000,000,000,000 possibilities

# Let's create some strings
for i in range(10000000):
    chars = gen_str()
    # Python set implemented as hash table so this is O(1). (It doesn't slow down as set grows)
    while chars in string_set:
        #Regenerate random number if collision
        #(This is has a n / (36^6) likelihood of happening where "n" is the number of elements in the set so far). Until you exceed 1 billion elements this is a non-issue
        chars = gen_str()
    print("adding to set: ", chars)
    string_set.add(chars)
```

The primary downside of this approach is you'll need to store your set somewhere (pickle and unpickle it) and this will presumably double your memory usage for each 8-char stored in the database. This will also become impossible if your set is too large for your system memory in which case your could look into the "shelve" module which provides a dict-like database object which you can use in basically the same way as a set by ignoring the values stored to each key.

Comment: I was trying to get the DB involved because I already have it; I need to have persistence in case the service restarts/fails. I think ill just have a set with the IDs and check if it already exists.

Comment: If a moderately long startup time is acceptable you could just create your set of IDs from the database once every time the service restarts and then follow a method similar to the main one I suggested. Alternatively the shelve module would offer you persistence of the set/dict itself but will have slower "add" and "in" operations.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and retrieve all ids into a set from the DB every time the service starts and check against the set. I'm overcomplicating things, this is not intended for production, I went down the rabbit hole thinking about performance. 
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's probably what I'd go with too, and I think what you describe will be more performant than you think actually. You're welcome.

Comment: one billion is a very optimistic. I would no go beyond few thousands. Keep in mind that 'toss' itself repeated many times. While typical number of elements is about one million, on a few test I got just several hundreds of thousands to get duplicate.

Comment: Yes but we're not trying to avoid a duplicate at all costs, all that matters is that the duplicates won't reach the point where they're so common that a we get a significant performance hit. Having to produce a second key even once per 100 is fairly insignificant and once every 100000 is truly negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use random generators directly. While python's random module is decent, with other languages I had some problems, e.g. when generating points in multidimensional space, some patterns were occurring.

Python support conversion to decimal integer from a base 36 numeral. So, to constraint the min value, convert string to integer and user *randint*, which readily supports intervals.

Conversion of regular base 10 integer into base 36 is more tricky, luckily you can use an additional library such or numpy or active state snipped from https://code.activestate.com/recipes/65212/. I just copied a sniped from an older stackoverflow answer, it was discussed many times, and more compact than activestates'.

```
import string
import random

alphabet = string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase
N = len(alphabet) # 36
MAX1 = int('0000WXYZ', N) + 1
MAX2 = int('ZZZZZZZZ', N)

digs = alphabet

def int2base(x, base):
    digits = []
    while x:
        digits.append(digs[int(x % base)])
        x = int(x / base)
    digits.reverse()
    return ''.join(digits)


r = int2base(random.randint(MAX1, MAX2), N)
if len(r) < 8:  # pad with 0 if needed
    r = rjust(r, '0')
```

Disclaimer. The python random number generator is quite good, yet, it is possible, since there is only so many unique string of the length 8. I run a few tests and usually it takes anywhere from a hundred thousand to a few millions. Even with a truly random numbers, you can get just anything, even duplicate, just try to toss a coin or roll a dice several times in row. Note, it is not great idea to update your the MAX each time as you will exhaust the list and reach the ZZZZZZZZ very soon (probably less than 30). If you feel strongly compelled 100% prevent duplicates, just build a list/set of already used strings, yet it is highly unlikely, unless MAX is close to ZZZZZZZZ.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to create unique combinations:

```
from itertools import permutations
alphabet = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
permutations(alphabet, 8)
```

If you want to draw random but continuously increasing numbers from all possible but unique entries you could try this:

```
# Get maximum of possible entries:
from functools import reduce
import operator
import math

counts = [8,36]
permuations = int(math.factorial(sum(counts))/reduce(operator.mul, map(math.factorial, counts), 1))

# Generate all possible entries (generator)
from itertools import permutations, islice
alphabet = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
g = permutations(alphabet, 8)

# select a list of random indexes to retrieve
from random import sample, seed
n = 5
seed(101)
lst = sorted(sample(range(0, permuations), 5))

# print 5 values from the original generator based on the random indexes
for i in lst:
    print(next(islice(g, i, None)))
```

Essentially you create all possible permutations (unique combinations) then you create a list of random but unique index. Now you order the index, which is why the outcome will always be increasing. Then you match the index by their coresponding value of all possible permutations.

Comment: Is it random? Can you guaranty each new number is not in the db?

Comment: @Serge, Thank you for pointing it out, I was under the assumption that would be enough to build the full solution, but when I actully did it, it became clear I undererstimated the full process. Updated my answer.

Comment: I wonder if this is slower than just checking for the existence of the id every time I generate one.

Comment: I think he would prefer arbitrary combinations to permutation, and you have discard permutations smaller than MAX

Comment: Look's like pretty slow, but not sure is it slower, faster or is it even work. Why do not you find out?